# An error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'when i install Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

When I install Scrappy, it tells me I successfully installed, but when i input >>scrapy in cmd , it reported an error

[image]

Help me please.

Comment: Can you check what Mikhail mentions in [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2473#issuecomment-283293204) ? You are probably using pyOpenSSLthat is not compatible with your Twisted version (Twisted apparently has not updated their requirements on pyOpenSSL). Upgrading pyOpenSSL using pip should fix this.

Comment: thank you very much．I have download a lower version Twisted,and it runs well now